# Cant get CRC function with Big Endian to work

Tags: c#, crc

I am having trouble getting a CRC function to work in C#. Below is the example C code given, below is the C# code I use. I suspect the culprit is the big endian, but when I switch the byte order of the checksum it still gives different values.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Many thanks

Matt

CRC is calculated using CRC-CCITT (Kermit) algorithm (http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crccalculation.html).

Parameter length – 2 bytes. Format is big endian. That is why bytes 0 and 1 are “switched”.

CRC calculation algorithm is shown below (C programming language).

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * FUNCTION: CRC16
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------    
 */
unsigned short crc_16_rec (unsigned char *pucData, unsigned short ucLen) {
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned char ucBit, ucCarry;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    unsigned short usPoly = 0x8408;//reversed 0x1021
    unsigned short usCRC = 0;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (i = 0; i < ucLen; i++) {
        usCRC ^= pucData[i];
        for (ucBit = 0; ucBit < 8; ucBit++) {
            ucCarry = usCRC & 1;
            usCRC >>= 1;
            if (ucCarry) {
                usCRC ^= usPoly;
            }
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    return usCRC;
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The code I use

```
public enum Crc16Mode : ushort { Standard = 0xA001, CcittKermit = 0x8408 }

Crc16 CRC = new Crc16(Crc16Mode.CcittKermit);

public class Crc16
    {


        readonly ushort[] table = new ushort[256];

        public ushort ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
        {
            ushort crc = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length - 2; ++i)
            {
                byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
                crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ table[index]);
            }
            return crc;
        }

        public bool ChecksumValid(ref byte[] bytes)
        {
            ushort checksum = (ushort)((bytes[bytes.Length - 2] << 8) | bytes[bytes.Length - 1]);
            ushort checksum_received = CRC16(bytes);
            if (checksum == checksum_received)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public ushort CRC16(byte[] bytes)
        {
            ushort crc = 0; //(ushort.maxvalue, 65535)

            for (int j = 0; j < bytes.Length; j++)
            {
                crc = (ushort)(crc ^ bytes[j]);
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                {
                    if ((crc & 0x0001) == 1)
                        crc = (ushort)((crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408);
                    else
                        crc >>= 1;
                }
            }
            return (ushort)~(uint)crc;
        }

        public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(params byte[] bytes)
        {
            ushort crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
            return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
        }

        public Crc16(Crc16Mode mode)
        {
            ushort polynomial = (ushort)mode;
            ushort value;
            ushort temp;
            for (ushort i = 0; i < table.Length; ++i)
            {
                value = 0;
                temp = i;
                for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                {
                    if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                    {
                        value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value >>= 1;
                    }
                    temp >>= 1;
                }
                table[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps [CRC16ccit](http://www.idothink.com/2008/07/c-crc16-ccitt.html)

Comment: You'd need to provide an example message with CRC that this is failing on.